# Apache spark & RDF with Python

Tags: python, apache-spark, rdf

I'm a beginner in Apache Spark, It's been a long time that I'm looking for some books/tutorials which talk about **Apache Spark & RDF** with **python**.

Comment: Why should there be a book about Apache Spark + RDF? Spark doesn't support RDF natively. You have to look for 3rd party libraries.

Comment: Aren't we supposed to avoid using StackOverflow to ask for recommendations?

Comment: @AKSW, Can you publish some links of that 3rd party libraries if you know some? thanks in advance.